# AND query in elasticsearch python

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

Records Stored in Elasticsearch:

```
"hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "test_doc",
      "_id" : "AVUHBSESPB1nLi5k2Dxp",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"valid": true,"action_taken": false}
    }, {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "test_doc",
      "_id" : "AVUHBI1IPB1nLi5k2Dxo",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"valid": true,"action_taken": false}
    }, {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "test_doc",
      "_id" : "AVUHWFipPB1nLi5k2Dxu",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"valid": false,"action_taken": false}
    } ]
```

We need to find those records whose valid is true and action_taken is false in python script using elasticsearch python package.

We are trying to do the same using

```
resp = ES.search(index='test', doc_type='test_doc', q='action_taken:0 valid:1)
```

However on execution, it returns all the records.
Is there any possible way to do the same using search.

PS: I am trying to write an API call which searches the records based on the search condition provided as json data in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you're sending to ElasticSearch doesn't look like a valid query. ES requires queries to be formatted in a specific way:

```
"query": {
    "match": {
        "content": term
    }
}
```

Based on this, I believe your need to change the `q` param.

For ElasticSearch pre `2.x`, the query should make use of the `filtered` and`filter` options. The query string is more similar to the SQL queries, so `and`, `or` filters are available ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-and-filter.html)):

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
           "and": [
                {"term": { "action_taken": 0 }},
                {"term": { "valid": 0 }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Starting ElasticSearch `2.3`, the `and` query is deprecated, and `bool` is suggested instead:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {"term": { "action_taken": 0 }},
            {"term": { "valid": 0 }}
         ]
    }
}
```

[Here is the link to the 2.3 docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Hope this helps. Let me know.

Comment: So should we need to pass the entire json suggested above as query parameter in the es search function call  `resp = ES.search(index='test', doc_type='test_doc',query = <above json>`)

Comment: It works using `resp = ES.search(index='test', doc_type='test_doc',body = <above json>)`